# How to allow zero/negative numbers in a textbox column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've searched online for an answer and I havn't come across anything helpful. Does anyone have any example code that may help?

Comment: what's the problem???

Comment: It's in the title. I'm attempting to add "0" or a negative number into a textbox column in a datagridview.. I'm not sure how to allow it to accept these as valid values.

Comment: The title doesn't give anyone any idea what the problem is.  Why don't you show your code?  a textbox column would allow any input, seeing your code will help 10000%

Comment: textbox treats data as string. You should handle your own validation and conversion to integer - so this is where you can enforce positive/negative and so on.